# query slow/delay empty collection Nodejs MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a big project and want to use a mongodb connection over multiple files.
The querys taking randomly 1-5s for a collection with only 1 document.

Here is an example where I get the same delay:

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
const uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
const opt = {poolSize:100};

let start = new Date().getTime();

let _db;

MongoClient.connect(uri,opt,(err, client)=>{
    console.log("connected");
    let db = client.db("easyLife");
    _db = db;
    console.log("time connect: "+(new Date().getTime() - start) + "s");
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        start = new Date().getTime();
        let users = _db.collection("users");
        users.findOne({_id:new ObjectID("5bdedb0ed4f00a8140a50cf6")}, function(err, res){
            console.log("time: "+(new Date().getTime() - start) + "s");
        });
    }
});
```

In my main project I initialize all events in the MongoClient.connect callback and have answers of 50ms to 5000ms.

The output of the example is

```
connected
time connect: 1040s
time: 3s
time: 1009s
time: 1010s
time: 2013s
time: 2014s
time: 2016s
time: 3020s
time: 3021s
time: 3022s
time: 3022s
```

Why they have such delays? What am I doing wrong?
I searched 2 days now, can't find a solution.

{ driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.1.9" }, os: { type: "Windows_NT", name: "win32", architecture: "x64", version: "10.0.17134" }, platform: "Node.js v10.13.0, LE, mongodb-core: 3.1.8" }

Comment: Your collection has an index set?

Comment: @JonathanBrizio index on _id but if i query for _id, same result :(

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: @JonathanBrizio yes but my query is optimized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that the connection pool size is slowly ramping up to meet to meet the needs of your client code. Set the `minSize` in your connection options to 10 and all 10 queries will immediately have a connection available:

```
let opt = {poolSize:100, minSize:10};
```